# Attaching Application load balancer / Network Load balancer directly with aws Autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

How do I attach aws Application Load Balancer and Network Load balancer directly with auto-scaling group(ASG)?
In AWS Console only available option is for **Classic Load Balancer**. 
What i want is whenever an instance is launched in autoscaling group it'll start reporting to **Application/Network** load balancer directly rather manually entering each instance in the **target group**.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/attach-load-balancer-asg.html?shortFooter=true#as-add-load-balancer-prerequisites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autoscaling group has the only direct option for the classic load balancer and target group. You can launch instances in the target group and select option for autoscaling group. Finally, attach your target group to ALB.

Answer (score -1):

While using ALB and NLB, you need to have Target Group created to wire an EC2 or ASG.
 So, you need ALB/NLB <- Target Group <- AutoScaling Group.

In Target Group you specify the instances/ips and ports you want to point.

Comment: I want directly attach ALB load balancer with autoscaling group(without managing EC2 instances in target group) like classic load balancer. When we add load balancer directly to autoscaling group so its self launch(instances)  while in Target group we self add instances.

Answer (score -1):

ALB and network load balancer can be added only via target groups/with ec2 mapped ... and not directly like classic load balancers.

Create a target group and follow the below steps;

```
Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.

On the navigation pane, under Auto Scaling, choose Auto Scaling Groups.

Choose an existing group from the list.

On the Details tab, choose Edit.

Do one of the following:

[Classic Load Balancers] For Load Balancers, choose your load balancer.

[Target groups] For Target Groups, choose your target group.

Choose Save.
```

Comment: I want directly attach ALB load balancer with autoscaling group(without managing EC2 instances in target group) like classic load balancer. When we add load balancer directly to autoscaling group so its self launch(instances)  while in Target group we self add instances.

Comment: ALB and network load balancer can be added only via target groups ... and not directly like classic load balancers.

Comment: I solve my problem. what I was asked in my Question?

Comment: can you please tell me how you did it ? Thanks

Comment: When instances running in Auto Scaling Group only mention the ALB Target Group in ASG, so instances is automatically added into registered instances(In ALB Target Group).No manual adding into registered instances(Target Group) its automatic process.